# Trying to create an array. Keep getting TypeError

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, typeerror

I'm trying to get a better grasp on the data structures.
I've been trying to add an array as an element of another array, but i keep getting the TypeError: Array item must be unicode character, when I try to create an array.  I'm following videos/everything I read to a T from what i can tell.

```
from array import array

Swords = array('u',['Steel Sword', 'Bronze Sword', 'Iron Sword'])
Axes = ['Steel Axe', 'Bronze Axe', 'Iron Axe']
Maces = ['Steel Mace','Bronze Mace','Iron Mace']
Bows = ['Wood Bow', 'Bone Bow', 'Obsidian Bow']
Daggers = ['Steel Dagger', 'Bronze Dagger', 'Obsidian Dagger']

Weapons = array('u',([Swords])

for i in Weapons:

    print(i)
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: The `'u'` type code corresponds to Python’s obsolete unicode character.  Why exactly are you trying to use the `array` datatype instead of a normal `list`?

Comment: @jk622 I was just trying to get comfortable working with arrays.  Is there any difference between an array, and a list in python, or should I just use a list when I need an array?

Comment: In general, you should be using a `list`.  Unless you are trying to use a particular function available to the `array` class, all you'd be doing is adding a constraint to the datatype of the objects inside it.

Comment: Ok, I did some additional reading, and makes sense when to use which.  Why the type error for trying to place a list inside of an array though?  This is what every tutorial I have watched has shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'u'` type code corresponds to Python’s obsolete unicode character.  This means it will work with unicode characters.  You can test this

```
test_one = array("u", ["\u2641","\u2642","\u2643"])
for i in test_one:
    print(i)
```

You can also see it with this

```
test_two = array("u", ["T","e","s","t"])
for i in test_two:
    print(i)
```

Notice, in both cases it is a single character.  Not entire strings.  In order to do the string, you would have to convert each string to a list of characters.

```
test_three = array("u", [ch for ch in "Test"])
for i in test_three:
    print(i)
```

Lastly, if you want to break down the individual characters from a list of strings you can do a list comprehension similar to `test_three` or you can use a generator.

```
def character_generator(word_list):
    for word in word_list:
        for ch in word:
            yield ch

test_four = array("u", character_generator(["Test","One","Two"]))
for i in test_four:
    print(i)
```

At the end of the day though, the `u` typecode is for individual characters.  Not strings.